# How to use Request::create and app handle in a commands at Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, request, laravel-artisan

I make a command to run routes from it. Like this one:

```
php artisan command:call --csrf=GCivIRtxYzHACOqJr3sasdasdGBJhR7q5X65VLv51K7 --user_id=1 --method=POST --path=/firms/load --data='{"id":2213}'
```

In a command i make:

```
    Auth::loginUsingId($this->option('user_id'));
    $params = json_decode($this->option('data'), true);
    if (!is_array($params)) {$params = [];}
    $params['_token'] = $this->option('csrf');
    $request = Request::create($this->option('path'), $this->option('method'), $params, ['XSRF-TOKEN' => $this->option('csrf')]);
    $request->headers->set('Authorization', $this->option('csrf'));
    $response = app()->handle($request)->getContent();
    echo $response;
```

But every time i get a page expires exception due a token missmatch.
What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What's your goal of this command?  Is there a reason you are trying to invoke the HTTP request flow in a command?

Comment: Yes, i make some loading through node.js server and want to place everything there. That's why i make exec artisan command with params

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the relationship between nodejs and trying to invoke a request flow in artisan. Normally, you should separate out business logic to a service layer which can be used in controllers or commands. The request flow to controllers should only be used for HTTP traffic.

Comment: I agree, but there is a lot of functional already and i want to make it easier somehow. My idea to use command and handle request. Any idea?

Comment: It's probably not worth doing it this way but how are you getting the CSRF token in the first place?  Normally CSRF tokens are session based.

Comment: I send it to nodejs server, then i send it to script through option. How i can set it before app hande request?